# how to store list of values in database ,with a primarykey autoincrement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

how to store list of values in database ,with a primarykey autoincrement
my dao have this primary key

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@Column(name = "ParamKey")
public long getParamKey() {
    return paramKey;
}

public void setParamKey(long paramKey) {
    this.paramKey = paramKey;
}
```

it is inserting for one row and it is showing the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

Comment: Post the code where you are persisting the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be the problem  :-

Actually when you deployed your application then hibernate **store the max id** and continuously **increased it by 1**.But in mean while if you directly insert the value in database then it will cause a problem because your hibernate is not aware of this thing.

So, On next insertion it assigns sequence_id+1 to next row but its already present in database
so it will gives you primary key constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
//Declaration
@Id
@GenericGenerator(strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "ParamKey")
private int paramKey;

//Getter
public long getParamKey(){
    return paramKey;
}
```

Comment: try do the same but on the declaration of 'paramKey' and remove the setParamKey... If it's a generated value it's important that you don't set it.

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long paramKey;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ParamKey")
 public long getParamKey() {
  return paramKey;
 } its giving the same error

Comment: thanks for that tip .. and now i came across with another problem i have a forignkey Client key   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "clientKey")
 public Client getClient() {
  return client;
 }

 public void setClient(Client client) {
  this.client = client;
 } its giving error Unknown column 'client' in 'field list

Comment: hibernate is querrying like this insert 
        into
            M_FeedInputParams
            (client, createdBy, createdTs, feedKey, jobInstanceKey, logicalDeleteTms, paramName, paramOper, paramValue, paramValueType, sourceInstanceKey, updatedBy, updatedTs) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "ParamKey")
 private long paramKey;

 public long getParamKey() {
  return paramKey;
 }

 @Column(name = "FeedKey")
 public long getFeedKey() {
  return feedKey;
 }

 public void setFeedKey(long feedKey) {
  this.feedKey = feedKey;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "clientKey")
 public Client getClient() {
  return client;
 }

 public void setClient(Client client) {
  this.client = client;
 }

Comment: use your Fetch as LAZY, not EAGER

Comment: Maybe it's better if you open other post... add your code and the errors you are getting...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your primary key like this in the class, that represents your table

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
```

Comment: should i create geter and seters for it

Comment: Yes, you should. You don't need annotations for them though :-).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `id` column in your table has the `autoincrement` option as `true`. (In the MySQL GUI, for example) Then use generation type `AUTO` as described before.